# You might dream about this puzzle

Tags: pattern, word-property

Find the pattern between these sets:

**1:** right, clocks, wings, hearted, yourself, strings

**2:** psychopath, bishop, withhold, breakthrough, shoplift, hopefully

**3:** bird, Vienna, tempt, modern, armadillo, center

**4:** rhinoceros, little Joe, maniacal, ludes, storage, quartet

**5:** veganism, betel nut, desiring, worthy, giving, pollution

**6:** AWOL, the rifleman, refillable, uninhabited, liferaft, fertile

**7:** priest, calming, youth, minister, choir, gas

Note that every set has two terms that shouldn't be in the set.

Hint:

> [music](/questions/tagged/music)

Hint 2:

> lyrics

## Final answer: (7, 3, 4, 2, 6)

Comment: Well, this Hint2 is not a surprise :-(